# How to get single color image from Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I upload a png-image with an alpha channel to the **drawable** folder. From this picture I get a **Bitmap**, which has transparency in certain places.

```
int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(bitmapName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resID);
```

I need to get a new **Bitmap** in which all colors are replaced by one color (for example, red), and the alpha channel should remain unchanged. There was a colored Bitmap with transparent areas, but I need a **Bitmap** with the same transparent areas, but the same color. Tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ hfontanez, I created a Bitmap from a png-file int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(bitmapName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resID); I don't know how to change the shade

Comment: You should update the question rather than posting the code as a comment.

Comment: @  hfontanez, fixed